# parent child Relationship

Tags: data-model

I'm having a little trouble with the terminology of a parent child relationship in salesforce.  If I have a custom object C that has an optional lookup to the account, custom object A and custom object B.

Is it correct to say that the parent is account, custom object A and B?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in the scenario you describe, the Account, custom object A, and custom object B could each be called a parent of custom object C.

Note that being a parent is different from being the master in a master-detail relationship. A master-detail relationship can be considered an extension of the parent-child relationship which adds more constraints. A parent-child relationship is merely a relationship between related pieces of data, whereas a master-detail relationship has further implications on the persistence of detail records when the master record is deleted, and the association of the detail record with the master. See the [overview of relationship types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm) for more details.